# Unable to fetch parameter pswLastSet from LDAP

Tags: java, active-directory

I'm having some problems with a Java function to search a Active Directory for a user and get the value of parameter pswLastSet.

This is my code:

```
public HashMap<String, String> passwordLastSet (String username, String wsUsername, String wsPassword){
                HashMap<String, String> password_info = new HashMap<String, String>();
                if(username == null || username.equals("")){
                    System.out.println("Invalid username");
                        password_info.put("Password_Expired", "Invalid Username");
                        password_info.put("Password_LastSet", "Invalid Username");
                        return password_info;
                }
                else if(wsUsername == null || wsUsername.equals("")){
                    System.out.println("Invalid wsUsername");
                        password_info.put("Password_Expired", "Invalid WsUsername");
                        password_info.put("Password_LastSet", "Invalid WsUsername");
                        return password_info;
                }
                else if(wsPassword == null || wsPassword.equals("")){
                    System.out.println("Invalid password");
                        password_info.put("Password_Expired", "Invalid WsPassword");
                        password_info.put("Password_Expired", "Invalid WsPassword");
                        return password_info;
                }
                else{

                String base_dn = "DC=fptindustrial,DC=local";           
                Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
                env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
                env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
                env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://MY_LDAP_URL:636");
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=MYUSER");
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "MYPASSWORD");

                try{
                     InitialDirContext ctx =  new InitialDirContext(env);
                     SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
                     String returnedAttrs[]={"pwdLastSet"};
                     searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAttrs);
                     searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
                     String searchFilter = "(&(samAccountName=userName))";
                     NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(base_dn, searchFilter, searchCtls);

                     System.out.println("Before SR");
                     SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();

                     System.out.println("After SR");

                     Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                     String pwdLastSet = attrs.get("pwdLastSet").toString();
                     pwdLastSetAttribute = pwdLastSet;

                     ctx.close();

               }catch(NamingException f) {
                     f.printStackTrace();
               }
              password_info.put("Password_Expired", "0");
              password_info.put("Password_LastSet", pwdLastSetAttribute);
            }
       return password_info;
}
```

The issue seems to be these two lines (from what I can understand):

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(base_dn, searchFilter, searchCtls);
SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
```

because I don't get any output from the SystemOut

```
System.out.println("After SR");
```

and also the HashMap password_info that is returned by the function is null.

Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: I added a

```
System.out.println("Before SR");
```

to the code to show exactly where it stops giving response. The "Before SR" is printed. The "After SR" is not.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code?

Comment: Hello Gabriel. I tried adding a series of SystemOut to check where the program stops, and I noticed that the one right before line SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next(); works, the one right after System.out.println("After SR"); does not.

Comment: Is an exception being thrown? Or are you waiting long enough to see what happens? That line is likely when it actually makes the network request.

Comment: No exception is being thrown. I just wait and I don't get any response or any println. Comunication between the server and the Active Directory is up, I tested it already.